# Modify subject in dependency message content

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm using postfix to send server notifications to another mail server who encrypt the content of the email with CipherMail (PGP). The second mail server forwarding the email to me.

I would like to modify the subject line in dependency of message body before the email sended to Server B.

Example:
If the email contain "Found an error", the subject should be change in "[Server A] Error".
If the email doesn't contain "Found an error", the subject should be change in "[Server A] Status".

Background: Before I installed CipherMail, I sorted my emails by content. Of course this doesn't work anymore with PGP encryption.

Anybody got an idea for that?